# Double reverse TCP proxy in C#?

Tags: c#, tcp, proxy

Edit: realized I need an implementation of this on C#:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relays_around_NAT

I'll try to find one, if anyone has one I'll appreciate it, thanks!

I might have just made up that name on the spot.

What I'm trying to do is have a computer that is behind NAT and will need to provide a service connect to a server.
Then, I would connect to that server using a third computer and interact with the TCP stream initiated by the first computer, in a way that would work just as if I had connected straight to it.

Found a way to create a forward proxy, which works great:
blog.brunogarcia.com/2012/10/simple-tcp-forwarder-in-c.html

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace TcpProxy
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new TcpForwarderSlim().Start(
    new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), int.Parse("69")),
    new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("91.198.174.192"), int.Parse("80")));
        }

    }
    public class TcpForwarderSlim
    {
        private readonly Socket _mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        public void Start(IPEndPoint local, IPEndPoint remote)
        {
            _mainSocket.Bind(local);
            _mainSocket.Listen(10);

            while (true)
            {
                var source = _mainSocket.Accept();
                var destination = new TcpForwarderSlim();
                var state = new State(source, destination._mainSocket);
                destination.Connect(remote, source);
                source.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, 0, OnDataReceive, state);
            }
        }

        private void Connect(EndPoint remoteEndpoint, Socket destination)
        {
            var state = new State(_mainSocket, destination);
            _mainSocket.Connect(remoteEndpoint);
            _mainSocket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnDataReceive, state);
        }

        private static void OnDataReceive(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            var state = (State)result.AsyncState;
            try
            {
                var bytesRead = state.SourceSocket.EndReceive(result);
                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    state.DestinationSocket.Send(state.Buffer, bytesRead, SocketFlags.None);
                    state.SourceSocket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, 0, OnDataReceive, state);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                state.DestinationSocket.Close();
                state.SourceSocket.Close();
            }
        }

        private class State
        {
            public Socket SourceSocket { get; private set; }
            public Socket DestinationSocket { get; private set; }
            public byte[] Buffer { get; private set; }

            public State(Socket source, Socket destination)
            {
                SourceSocket = source;
                DestinationSocket = destination;
                Buffer = new byte[8192];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

[UPNP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333079) can open a port on a properly configured router.

[STUN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339688), ICE, and [TURN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096335) use intermediary servers to connect when ports can't be opened. There are open source [server implementations](http://officesip.org/).

UDP can use [UDP Hole Punching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136031).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8524609/) provides a more detailed explaination but not much C# help.